# How to read this file using Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a DNA file in the following format:

```
>gi|5524211|gb|AAD44166.1| cytochrome
ACCAGAGCGGCACAGCAGCGACATCAGCACTAGCACTAGCATCAGCATCAGCATCAGC
CTACATCATCACAGCAGCATCAGCATCGACATCAGCATCAGCATCAGCATCGACGACT
ACACCCCCCCCGGTGTGTGTGGGGGGTTAAAAATGATGAGTGATGAGTGAGTTGTGTG
CTACATCATCACAGCAGCATCAGCATCGACATCAGCATCAGCATCAGCATCGACGACT
TTCTATCATCATTCGGCGGGGGGATATATTATAGCGCGCGATTATTGCGCAGTCTACG
TCATCGACTACGATCAGCATCAGCATCAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCAGCTACGAC
```

How do I read this file and extract the DNA sequence part (`ACCAGAGCGG...`) without any newlines, for example:

```
ACCAGAGCGGCACAGCAGCGACATCAGCACTAGCACTAGCATCAGCATCAGCATCAGCCTACATCATCACAGCAGCATCA
```

Maybe regex isn't needed?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions about Python on this DNA project.

Comment: @jed - but at least answers are being marked as accepted (and hopefully upvoted).

Comment: I'm kind of a noob at python is why.

Comment: While I love python if you want speed for this type of calculation you should be using <a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/staff/tao/URLAPI/blastall/blastall_node13.html">Blastall</a>, while it maybe a little show to pick up it will surely be better than reinventing the wheel. Here is a <a href="http://bips.u-strasbg.fr/fr/Tutorials/Comparison/Blast/blastall.html">tutorial</a> that looks good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there's always only one line of header :

```
dnalines = text.split('\n')[1:]
dna = ''.join(dnalines)
```

With text = the contents of your file (for example, `text = open('yourfile').read()`)

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests, and it appears that the following is more efficient than [delroth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738524/how-to-read-this-file-using-python/1738538#1738538):

```
text.split('\n', 1)[1].replace('\n', '')
```

**Edit:** wait, it's not so simple. I timed both methods, twice, using Python 2.6.4 and 3.1.1, on an ~30MB file:

- Python 2.6.4, my version:

  ```
  $ python -m timeit -c "open('x').read().split('\n', 1)[1].replace('\n', '')"
  10 loops, best of 3: 221 msec per loop
  $ python -m timeit -c "open('x').read().split('\n', 1)[1].replace('\n', '')"
  10 loops, best of 3: 219 msec per loop
  ```
- Python 2.6.4, delroth's version:

  ```
  $ python -m timeit -c "''.join(open('x').read().split('\n')[1:])"
  10 loops, best of 3: 392 msec per loop
  $ python -m timeit -c "''.join(open('x').read().split('\n')[1:])"
  10 loops, best of 3: 390 msec per loop
  ```
- Python 3.1.1, my version:

  ```
  $ python3 -m timeit -c "open('x').read().split('\n', 1)[1].replace('\n', '')"
  10 loops, best of 3: 803 msec per loop
  $ python3 -m timeit -c "open('x').read().split('\n', 1)[1].replace('\n', '')"
  10 loops, best of 3: 798 msec per loop
  ```
- Python 3.1.1, delroth's version:

  ```
  $ python3 -m timeit -c "''.join(open('x').read().split('\n')[1:])"
  10 loops, best of 3: 610 msec per loop
  $ python3 -m timeit -c "''.join(open('x').read().split('\n')[1:])"
  10 loops, best of 3: 610 msec per loop
  ```

Conclusion: *Python 3 is **much** slower, and it depends on the Python version which of the two code snippets is faster!*